# Can you put a DrawableShape or Shape, "directly in" a layout?

Tags: android, xml, drawable

In the main activity XML file of my app, I have a layout, with some ImageView:

```
<LinearLayout
..>
<ImageView
    .../>
<ImageView
    ..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

No problem so far. Separately, I define blob.xml which is just a large white dot.

blob.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <size android:width="32dp" android:height="32dp"/>
</shape>
```

Of course, I can put the blob "in" an ImageView like this:

```
<LinearLayout
..>
<ImageView
    .../>
<ImageView
    ..."/>
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/blob"
    .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

That's all fantastic.  I'll never develop for iOS again!  But is there a way to simply directly put a "shape" inside the layout XML?  So, something like..

```
<LinearLayout
..>
<ImageView
    .../>
<ImageView
    ..."/>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <size android:width="32dp" android:height="32dp"/>
</shape>
</LinearLayout>
```

or perhaps ...

```
<LinearLayout
..>
<ImageView
    .../>
<ImageView
    ..."/>
<ImageView
android:src={
   <shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <size android:width="32dp" android:height="32dp"/>
   </shape>
   }
   >
</LinearLayout>
```

Or something like that!

Again, essentially "not using a separate drawable/ file"

Is this possible? Sorry, it's difficult to find this, as such, documented in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to define an **inline Drawable** (yet)

---

Anyway, if you feel masochist, you can **build a drawable in Java** and then assign it to your View.
But this, in my opinion, would be kind of an overkill.

I only use this technique when **forced**.

---

Further on (if you really feel depraved **;)**), there's another technique which consists in making a **custom View** and **override the onDraw method** to completely draw it on your own.

I use this technique only if I must build something really new (i.e.: some View not available among the standard ones), such as a rotating knob or a gauge or whatever.

Kind of a pain, but it gives its results.

Comment: Agreed it is not possible, you would just reference the drawable file as an external resource.

Comment: Magnificent.  Thanks men!  To be absolutely clear **you can not put a '<shape' inline** is that right?

Comment: regarding "override onDraw".  that's what we have to do every single time in iOS .. to do anything  :)

Comment: I don't envy iOS developers... ;)

Comment: Well, you still have the ability of making things "a la iOS", when everything else doesn't fit your needs ;)